# Asymptotic expansion of root of $\epsilon x \tan(x)=1$

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

> Indicate a range of roots of $\epsilon x \tan(x)=1$ for which it is impossible to get an approximation using expansions.

Since $\epsilon$ is small, I think for the equation to hold, we need either $x \to \infty$ or $x=k \pi+\pi/2$.

I think the root $x \to \infty$ may be the root the problem is looking for. Since $tan(x)$ is oscillating in infinity. I am not sure if this is right and I am having trouble to justify it.

Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: May be after expansion we can get finite term equal infinity term, then contradiction? However, I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: What does "impossible to get an approximation using expansions" mean?  It seems to me that each root of the equation can be approximated for small $\epsilon$ and they all tend toward $\pm(k\pi + \pi/2)$ for $k > 0$ integer.

Comment: @AntonioVargas What about $x$ is the size of $1/\epsilon$, is that also a possible solution?

Comment: To which root are you referring?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I am not sure. I mean $x$ is of size $1/\epsilon$ and $tan(x)$ is of size $1$.